# Is there a conflict between jQuery UI "autocompleteselect" event and AngularJs event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know if there is a known conflict between jQuery UI "autocompleteselect" event and some AngularJS event?

Here is my case :
I have a table and an autocomplete input

```
<label for="addFruit">Add a fruit</label>
<input type="text" fruit-autocomplete ng-model="fruit"/>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:fruitsOrder">
            <td>
                {{fruit.label}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a title="Remove" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="rmFruit(fruit)">
                    Remove
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have declared my autocomplete in a directive

```
app.directive('fruitAutocomplete', ['$http', function($http){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){

        element.autocomplete({
            select : function(event, ui){
                scope.fruit = ui.item; // Stores the selected fruit
                scope.addFruit(); // Perform addFruit()
            },
            source: ... //Get my custom Json source
        }).data('autocomplete') .... // Render in ul

    };
}]);
```

And here is a part of the content of my controller

```
/*
 * Methods
 */
// Add a fruit method
$scope.addFruit = function(){
    this.fruits.push({'label' : 'test'}); // Add a new fruit to fruits
};

// Remove a fruit method
$scope.rmFruit = function(fruitToRemove){
    var index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruitToRemove);
    this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.fruit  = null; // the selected fruit
$scope.fruits = fruitsList; // fruitList is the object containing all the fruits
$scope.fruitsOrder = 'label';
```

Everything works fine! Except when I select something in the autocomplete list. 
Indeed, when I select an item, the `select` option is well fired and `scope.addFruit()` too (my `$scope.fruits` object is updated too!). But my `table` is not immediately updated!

So I tried to add a button "Add" which would fire the same method as my autocomplete `select`. Like this :

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="addFruit()">
    Add
</button>
```

When clicked the `scope.addFruit()` is fired, and surprisingly, my `table` is immediately updated!

I searched and discovered that, when I select something in my autocomplete list, and then type something in my autocomplete field, my `table` is updated. So it seems that something is happening with an "on change" event somewhere.

Maybe some of you have experienced this situation or maybe I am just missing a point somewhere in my code. Maybe should I use `$watch`? or another method?

Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try wrapping your 'select' callback with $scope.$apply function.

```
  ...
  select : function(event, ui){
    scope.$apply(function(){
      scope.fruit = ui.item; // Stores the selected fruit
      scope.addFruit(); // Perform addFruit()
    });
  },
  ...
```

You can read more about $apply function in [Scope Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).

Comment: Wow Thanks for your reply :) It works perfectly. I missed that method thank you!

Comment: @JulienRodrigues Thank you for taking time to write a practical and answerable question.